# Parsing php string in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, array, json

I am sending php array using serialise but the response is different. Here is my attempt

```
$array = serialize($out);
var_dump(serialize($array));
//string(58) "s:50:"a:2:{s:9:"sidebar-1";i:5;s:12:"footer-insta";i:2;}";"
```

The way I am sending this value,

```
echo '<div data-ad = '.$array.' class="ash_loadmore"><span>LOAD MORE</span></div>';
```

As I am sending the serialised value using ajax, the value that ajax response give me,

```
string(54) "a:2:{s:9:\"sidebar-1\";i:5;s:12:\"footer-insta\";i:2;}"
```

I need the exact value as I have unserialise again to make it array. Why there is extra `\` and output is different.

Comment: Why are you serializing it? If you need to make a PHP array available for use in JavaScript, use json_encode to encode it as JSON.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, Thanks for suggestion I will try that in wordpress to see how it can be done .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it seems @JacobPeattie mentioned to use json, I just echoing that.

1. First json encode the variable `$array = json_encode($out);`
2. Then send this value `echo '<div data-ad = '.$array.' class="ash_loadmore"><span>LOAD MORE</span></div>';`
3. To get that `echo json_encode($_POST['ad'])`

I think that's it.BTW you don't have now that string problem as the output will be like this `{"footer-insta":2,"sidebar-1":3}` you see it is wrapped by `{}`

Answer (score 0):

Well, this `\` is getting added to escape the `"`. For example you are storing the whole string `"sidebar-1"`. Notice the string contains opening `"` and also closing `"`. Now the string is also wrapped with another `""`, so for separating the opening `"` and closing `"` of the stored string it's adding a `\` to escape it. This way it makes it hidden form parsing the `""` of the stored string as a real quote.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and least problematic solution:

```
$array = json_encode($out);
var_dump(array); // string "{\"sidebar-1\":5,\"footer-insta\":2}"
```

In JS you can use:

```
JSON.parse("{\"sidebar-1\":5,\"footer-insta\":2}")
```

and you have object with data